# Change a mysql column from text to bigint

Tags: mysql

I want to change column datatype from text to bigint

first i check the count of data in table1 is 100000

then run this query

`` ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE COLUMN `column1` `column1` BIGINT NOT NULL; ``

and check the total count again and still get the same count which is 100000

but got an warning says incorrect integer value : 'null' for column 'column_name' at row 12345

and i was wondering if this is something we should be worried about ?

Comment: Check old value for this row.

Comment: If you change the column data type how you are expecting the count should return a different value ?

Comment: It means you have a `NULL` value in the column. I expect the table's `column1` datatype is still `TEXT`, is it? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;` after the `ALTER` syntax and see if `column1` is already changed to `BIGINT` or not.

Comment: Thanks yeah your right there are null value on my column !